# How to delete a user in MongoDB 3.6

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I was in trouble with deleting the users in mongodb3.6.

I created a user with:

```
db.createUser({ user: "username" , pwd: "password", roles: ["root"]})
```

And I deleted it with:

```
db.dropUser("username")
```

Also in mongodb.conf I commented :

```
auth = true
```

However, afer restarting mongo, I tried to check the dbs and I got an error like this:
[image]

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You enabled authorization and re-started mongod. So now you need to get authenticated to check the dbs.

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I made a mistake when describe the problem that I should say I commented the statement about the authentication, and I still can't solve the problem now.

Comment: This scenario is perfectly working fine for me.  Please check mongod.log for any useful information.